# Source code pretty printer with DocBook or XML output?

Tags: xml, pretty-print, docbook

Is there some source code pretty printer out there that is able to generate DocBook, or at least XML output from my C sources?

I want to include some good looking source code examples in my DocBook document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by a pretty-printer that generates XML, but if you want code examples in DocBook documents to be nicely colourized when transformed to HTML or FO/PDF output, take a look at [XSLTHL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xslthl/). This is an XSLT extension module (written in Java) that decorates the content of `<programlisting>` elements.

For details on using XSLTHL with with the DocBook XSL stylesheets, see http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/html/highlight.source.html.

Comment: Yes, this is something close to what I want. Optimally, I want to keep the original C sources intact, but this is not a big issue I think, all I need is to put the C source into a <programlisting> and replace the '<', '>', '&' characters. Thanks!

Comment: Finally I went with [GNU source highlite](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) which has DocBook output.